# Clear Filter Angular 6

Tags: angular, button, filter, angular-material, reset

I have a table with a filter like this:

```
<form  [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
         <input matInput formControlName="nameFilter">
      </mat-form-field> 
  <button mat-raised-button class="search">Search</button>
</form>

<button mat-raised-button class="reset" (click)="resetFilter()">Reset</button>
```

What should I insert in my TS to be able to cancel the filter?
Do I need to insert the button "filter" inside the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FormGroup itself has a reset method. Just call it.

```
<button mat-raised-button class="reset" (click)="form.reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
form  #myform="ngForm" [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
         <input matInput formControlName="nameFilter">
      </mat-form-field> 
  <button mat-raised-button class="search">Search</button>
</form>

<button mat-raised-button class="reset" (click)="resetFilter(myform)">Reset</button>
```

ts

```
class MyFormComponent {
 @ViewChild('myform') form;

 resetFilter(form) {
  // you can access form via viewchild or via parameter
  this.myform.controls['nameFilter'].value = null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the reset method of angular which is the default form method. You need to call this method on click of reset filter and clear form group name which is following

```
resetFilter() { this.contactForm.reset(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the reset() of Form API

```
<button mat-raised-button class="reset" (click)="form.controls.nameFilter.reset()">Reset</button>
```